# Keep the same JavaFX buttons between scenes

Tags: java, button, javafx

I want to display the same buttons between each scene in my program but I cannot seem to find a way to do this. I want to have buttons which will be displayed on every scene but these buttons will also be used to change between scenes.

I currently have a working program but the problem is that the highlighted button does not represent which scene is currently being displayed. This is because I recreate each button every time a scene is loaded therefore not keeping its old data.

Comment: https://github.com/sedj601/RestaurantOrdersDuplicateFX

Answer (score 1):

Your design is fundamentally wrong. The GUI should not be used to represent the state of your system. There should be some kind of model for this purpose. Once you have created such a model it does not matter anymore how many Buttons or other GUI elements you create because they will just reflect whatever the state of your model is.